# ftp failing to retrieve directory listing

Tags: networking, arch-linux, ftp, vsftpd, filezilla

I'm trying to connect to my ftp server but I'm getting

```
Status: Disconnected from server
Status: Connecting to 127.0.0.1:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/home/jenia" is the current directory
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Switching to Binary mode.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (127,0,0,1,240,11).
Command:    LIST
Response:   150 Here comes the directory listing.
Error:  Connection closed by server
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

I don't understand what the problem is in terms of establishing a connection between my ftp client (Filezilla) and my server.

This is all in contrast to when I shut down `vsftpd`:

```
Status: Connecting to 127.0.0.1:21...
Status: Connection attempt failed with "ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server".
Error:  Could not connect to server
Status: Waiting to retry...
Status: Connecting to 127.0.0.1:21...
Status: Connection attempt failed with "ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server".
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

Why the `Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing`?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I'm connecting to `127.0.0.1` because I get (probably) the same problem on my Android phone and decided to try Filezilla to begin to investigate the problem.

Comment: Does it work if you set it in `active` instead of `passive` mode?

Comment: How does your `/etc/vsftpd.conf` looks?  Also, how big is the directory listing (as in: how many files, hundreds?)?